# Which is the best one, ContentView or Inheriting from an layout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Which is the best way to reuse views in xamarin forms ?

By inheriting from a layout or Content View or from a view ? 
When considering the performance is there any thing difference ?

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Inheriting from a View is normally the way to do it for a single control. A layout is a control that can have View's as children as well as being a View as well.

Comment: thank you for this information, Is there any performance difference in using a content views  when compared to inheriting from a layout.?

Comment: A layout might be a little bit slower due to it rendering child objects but the difference would be incredibly minor.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information on the performance, that was really helpful.